# How monitory live response and make decision with python?

Tags: python, checkmarx

I'm doing an integration with Checkmarx.

I sent the request to create a new report, it worked well. But, the proccess take a time, so, I need to wait to report be create and download it.

https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/222069127/Get+Report+Status+by+Id+-+GET+reports+sastScan+id+status+v8.6.0+to+v8.7.0

Sample Response:
{
"location": "/reports/sastScan/1",
"contentType": "application/xml",
"status": {
"id": 2,
"value": "In Process"
}
}

Sample Response:
{
"location": "/reports/sastScan/1",
"contentType": "application/xml",
"status": {
"id": 2,
"value": "Created"
}
}

I'd like to know how create a monitoring in python when the "value" is "Created" get it and continue my python script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option would be to have a while loop after your initial post that stays looping until the status turns to created. The psuedocode for this would be

```
post_request()
flag = false
while(flag == false):
    if(status == complete):
        flag = true
get_status()
```

This will trap the program in the while loop until your request comes in.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!